# Python - Vectorize an iterative algorithm for battery state of charge tracker

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an excel template that tracks state of charge of a battery (per hour) based on a column of surplus or shortfall energy. It also tracks the charging and discharing of the battery.

I am trying to convert this to python (using pandas) at a much larger scale (~40 million rows)

The logic is as follows:

1. if there is a surplus, then charge
2. if there is a shortfall, then discharge
3. the max state of charge (soc) can only be 80 and the min soc has to be 0.
4. the max that can be charged or discharged in one hour is 20
5. we start with soc of 80

The data looks like such:

```
hour | surplus_shortfall
------------------------
1      15
2     -84
3     -70
4     -60
5     -50
6     -30
7      10
8      36
9      45
10     60
11     22
12    -10
13    -23
14    -8
```

We can use `np.where` to create columns for `max_charge` and `max_discharge` respectively; e.g., `data['max_charge] = np.where(data['surplus_shortfall'] > 0, np.min(data['surplus_shortfall'], 20), 0)`

I also need to track columns for the actual amount charged, `actual_charge` (b/c recall soc cannot exceed 80) and actual amount discharged `actual_discharge`(b/c soc cannot go below 0). Finally, I need columns for `initial_soc` and `end_soc`

I will define data points for the first row below.

For the first row, we can define the following:

- `actual_charge` will always be 0, `data.loc[0, 'actual_charge'] = 0` as we start off fully charged
- `actual_discharge` will be `data.loc[0, 'actual_discharge'] = np.where(data.loc[0, 'max_discharge'] == 0, 0, data.loc[0, 'max_discharge']`.
- The `initial_soc` is defined as `data.loc[0, initial_soc] = 80`
- `end_soc` as `data.loc[0, 'end_soc'] = data.loc[0, 'initial_soc'] + data.loc[0, 'actual_charge'] - data.loc[0, 'actual_discharge']`

Now, the resulting table looks like this:

```
hour | surplus_shortfall | initial_soc | max_charge | max_discharge | actual_charge | actual_discharge | end_soc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       15                 80            15            0               0              0                 80            
2      -84                               0             20
3      -70                               0             20
4      -60                               0             20
5      -50                               0             20
6      -30                               0             20
7       10                               10            0
8       36                               20            0
9       45                               20            0  
10      60                               20            0
11      22                               20            0
12     -10                               0             10
13     -23                               0             10
14     -8                                0             8
```

What I would like to do is fill out the rest of the rows in the same way. But the problem is `initial_soc` depends on the `end_soc` from the previous row.

If I had a pseudo algorithm to do this it would be like so:

```
for row in dataframe:
    if row == 0:
        continue
    # define initial_soc as the end_soc of the previous row
    row['initial_soc'] = row['end_soc'}.shift()  # syntax to access previous item in loop escaping me atm
    # define actual_discharge
    if row['initial_soc'] != 0:
        row['actual_discharge'] = np.min(row['max_discharge'], row['initial_soc'])
    else
        row['actual_discharge'] = 0
    # define actual_charge
    if row['initial_soc'] < 80:
        row['actual_charge'] = np.min(row['max_discharge'], 80 - row['initial_soc'])
    elif row['initial_soc'] == 80:
        row['actual_charge'] = 0
    # calculate end_soc
    row['end_soc'] = row['initial_soc'] + row['actual_charge'] - row['actual_discharge']
```

The resulting table would look like this:

```
hour | surplus_shortfall | initial_soc | max_charge | max_discharge | actual_charge | actual_discharge | end_soc
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      15                  80            15           0               0               0                  80            
2      -84                 80            0            20              0               20                 60     
3      -70                 60            0            20              0               20                 40 
4      -60                 40            0            20              0               20                 20              
5      -50                 20            0            20              0               20                 0
6      -30                 0             0            20              0               0                  0 
7       10                 0             10           0               10              0                  10            
8       36                 10            20           0               20              0                  30            
9       45                 30            20           0               20              0                  50
10      60                 50            20           0               20              0                  70
11      22                 70            20           0               10              0                  80 
12     -10                 80            0            10              0               10                 70
13     -23                 70            0            20              0               20                 50
14     -8                  50            0            8               0               8                  42
```

I am not married to having these exact columns. All that really matters is keeping track of the SOC somehow and then knowing how much is actually charged or discharged at every hour.

I have tried to vectorize it using some combinations of `.cumsum()` and `.clip()` with no luck.

Any ideas on how to go about this without using a clunky loop (again the 40 million rows I have would make this very tedious)?

Comment: Is this for work, by any chance? Because the company I'm joining does exactly this. I hope that the data you've posted is dummy data, not the real thing.

Comment: It is dummy data lol and completely without labels :)

Comment: Well, considering that the process of finding the `soc` values is necessarily sequential, I honestly don't see how vectorisation can be an option. Vectorisation is for stuff where every row, column, or element is independent of the others. It's not for sequential code. But for 40 million rows, maybe just reducing the number of `if` statements and columns you've got will speed things up -- some of them look somewhat unnecessary, and for making your data smaller reduces the chances that some of your data will be stored in RAM and not cache (unless you're chunking your calculations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wasn't able to get rid of the `for` loop because your code is sequential, and vectorisation is for code that can be parallelised. I think I was able to simplify (and maybe speed up? Haven't timed it yet) some of your code with native Pandas and NumPy methods, meaning I could get rid of all the `if` statements in your pseudocode. I also got rid of some columns which looked completely unnecessary (explanations at bottom).

Here's my code:

```
max_soc = 80
max_charge_rate = 20

# I combined max_charge and max_discharge into 1 column.
# Positive indicates a charge value; negative indicates a discharge value.
df["max_charge_or_discharge"] = df["surplus_shortfall"].clip(lower = -max_charge_rate, upper = max_charge_rate)

# soc_values will eventually contain all the end_soc values.
# I am foregoing initial_soc.
soc_values = [max_soc]

# soc_diffs is a combination of actual_charge and actual_discharge, again with charge values being positive
# and discharge values being negative.
soc_diffs = []
max_charge_or_discharge_np = df["max_charge_or_discharge"].to_numpy()

for i in range(len(df)):
  last_soc_val = soc_values[-1]
  soc_val = np.clip(last_soc_val + max_charge_or_discharge_np[i], a_min = 0, a_max = max_soc)

  soc_diffs.append(soc_val - last_soc_val)
  soc_values.append(soc_val)

# Add columns to df.
df["end_soc_values"] = soc_values[1:]
df["soc_diffs"] = soc_diffs
```

And here's a little bonus section on how to get the `max_charge`, `max_discharge`, `actual_charge`, and `actual_discharge` columns as they appear in your `df` version, from the values in my version of the final `df`:

```
max_charge = df["max_charge_or_discharge"].mask(df["max_charge_or_discharge"] < 0, 0)
max_discharge = df["max_charge_or_discharge"].mask(df["max_charge_or_discharge"] >= 0, 0) * -1

actual_charge = df["soc_diffs"].mask(df["soc_diffs"] < 0, 0)
actual_discharge =  df["soc_diffs"].mask(df["soc_diffs"] >= 0, 0) * -1
```

Reasons for combining/getting rid of columns:

1. In your version, `max_charge = 0` when `max_discharge != 0` and vice versa. This is wasted space. Since having positive values to indicate one thing and negative values to indicate another thing is working just fine for the `surplus_shortfall` column, there's no reason the `max_charge_or_discharge` column can't follow the same logic.
2. I decided not to include `initial_soc` because that column is *exactly* the same as `end_soc`, just shifted by 1 row. That's 40 million extra values, just because `initial_soc` has an extra 80 at the top. Given that the `initial_soc` of each row is just that row's `end_soc - soc_diffs`, the `initial_soc` column doesn't even tell you anything new -- it's unnecessary and wasted space.
3. Honestly, if you're able to make a note somewhere that the `initial_soc` of the top row is 80, you don't even need the `soc_diffs` column.

Here's how you'd find `soc_diffs` if the `soc_diffs` column weren't there in the `df`:

```
end_soc_values_np = df["end_soc_values"].to_numpy()
end_soc_values_np = np.concatenate(([max_soc], end_soc_values_np))
soc_diffs = end_soc_values_np[1:] - end_soc_values_np[:-1]
```

Let me know if you have any questions.